# jPlayer - how to play tracks continuously?

Tags: jplayer

Can't figure this out - I simply want it to carrying on playing the next track when a song is finished.. autoplay set to true.. can't see what's throwing this out?

http://bavanandan.co.uk/press/

Answer (score 0):

(I know, it's old, but I was just searching for a solution myself and stumbled upon this.)

How about

```
                    var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist( {
                        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1" },
                        [],
                        {
                            swfPath: "wolf-jplayer/assets/js/src",
                            wmode: "window",
                            ended: function() {
                                // continouos play
                                var i = i+1;
                                myPlaylist.play(i);
                            }
                        }); //jPlayerPlaylist
```